# Unable to pass secureFile as a build argument to docker build task in Azure Pipelines

Tags: docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

I'm unable to pass secureFile as a build argument to docker build task in Azure Pipeline. Here are the tasks that i'm using in my yaml:

```
- task: DownloadSecureFile@1
  name: secret_key
  inputs:
    secureFile: id_rsa

- task: Docker@2
  displayName: Build Image
  inputs:
    containerRegistry: '<repository>'
    repository: '<image>'
    command: 'build'
    Dockerfile: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Dockerfile'
    buildContext: '.'
    tags: |
      $(Tag)
      latest
    arguments: '--build-arg key=$(secret_key.secureFilePath)'
```

This is the output that i'm seeing from the docker build.

```
#16 RUN echo id_rsa > /root/.ssh/id_rsa
#18 RUN cat /root/.ssh/id_rsa
#18 0.332 id_rsa
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output `$(secret_key.secureFilePath)` specifies the `location` of the secure file that was downloaded, it's string not the file itself or its content.

It will download the secure file to `$(Agent.TempDirectory)` on the agent. For example:

`D:\a\_temp\id_rsa`(windows) and `/home/vsts/work/_temp/id_rsa`(ubuntu linux).

[image]

If you pass the `$(secret_key.secureFilePath)` in the docker argument, it's only the string which points the temp folder secure file on the agent, which cannot be accessed from docker directly.

To use the downloaded secure file, you can firstly copy it to agent working directory, then in dockerfile, copy it into docker.

In your yaml:

```
    - task: DownloadSecureFile@1
      name: secret_key
      inputs:
        secureFile: id_rsa
    
    - script: echo $(secret_key.secureFilePath)
    - script: cp $(secret_key.secureFilePath) .   # copy the secure file to working directory.

    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Build and push an image to container registry
      inputs:
        containerRegistry: '$(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)'
        repository: '$(imageRepository)'
        command: 'build'
        Dockerfile: '**/Dockerfile'
        tags: |
         $(tag)
         latest
```

In your dockerfile, you can copy the file from agent working directory to docker to use:

[image]

I listed the file in docker for a check:

[image]

You can copy it as /root/.ssh/id_rsa again docker if needed.

Comment: Thank you @wade zhou - MSFT. Really appreciate for responding to my issue. Yes, i did look at this option through another post but i was curious if there are other methods to do it.